# No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin

Tags: java, oracle, maven, jdbc, junit

Пишу тест с иcпользованием запросов к БД и использую ojdbc6.jar. Пока тесты запускались руками из Idea проблем не было. Но как только возникла необходимость стартануть из консоли вот так:

```
c:\Users\petrov\IdeaProjects\petrovsProj>mvn -f pom.xml clean test && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
```

Выводит:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin

и т.д.

Сама библиотека добавлена в проект и лежит в `CLASSPATH`. В Idea все по-прежнему коннектится замечательно.

Кто сталкивался?

Коннект получаю так:

```
    private static Connection getDBOraConnection() {
    String url = ORA_JDBC_URL;
    String urlPg = GREENPLUM_JDBC_URL;

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, DB_ORACLE_ACCOUNT_USER, DB_ORACLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Additional.printLogString("  FAIL! There is err due to getDBOraConnection");
        Additional.printLogString("  "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return dbConnection;
}
```

PS Ради интереса попробывал даже локальный томкат с Jenkins развернуть, и в его класс путь прописать библиотеку, все выполняется нормально только до этапа создания подклюения с БД и затем "No suitable driver".

Comment: Покажите CLASSPATH который генерится из консоли

Comment: тест, особенно юнит, не должен ходить в базу

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался, была путаница в описаниях, тест не юнит, а интеграционный.

Answer (score 1):

Решилось, оставлю, если кто такой же невнимательный столкнется:
Получилось путем добавления драйвера в локальный репо с соответствующей записью

```
<dependency>
<groupId>oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
<version>11.2.0</version>
```

Есть момент - в буржуйских описаниях указаны такие настройки

```
<dependency>
<groupId>oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
<version>11.2.0.3</version>
```

При этом они советуют ставить драйвер так:

```
$ mvn install:install-file -Dfile={Path/to/your/ojdbc6.jar}-DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

но при такой установке версия в dependencies должна быть 11.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Драйвера Oracle отсутствуют в общедоступных репозиториях maven, т.к. у Oracle есть свой maven репозиторий, который следует подключить к проекту если необходимо загружать драйвера мавеном при сборке проекта. Здесь есть инструкция по настройке [Get Oracle JDBC drivers and UCP from Oracle Maven Repository (without IDEs)](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-oracle-maven-repository-without-ides)